# opencv function transpose() giving false results, memory leak?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I have a matrix of integer data type having dimensions 100 x 7000. I want to transpose it. I've used transpose() function from opencv library. but it gives the false results. Most of the values becomes floating point numbers and very high, which are not present in the original matrix. Here is my code

`cv::Mat data; //data matrix with integer values, dimension is 100 x 7000
 cv::Mat data_tp = cv::Mat(data.cols, data.rows, CV_32F);
 cv::transpose(data, data_tp);`

I think this might be the problem of memory leak or any sort of memory mismanagement. because this is just a part of a big code. Any tips regarding the memory management or anyone else faced this issue??

Comment: Try testing this part of the code in isolation, as you may have the wrong culprit - it's possible you have some sort of heap-corrupting bug earlier in the program. Also try running under valgrind to catch any memory-related errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cv::Mat data; //data matrix with integer values, dimension is 100 x 7000
// here are 2 problems:
// - you never need to pre-allocate the result.
// - you try to transpose an int Mat into a float one.
cv::Mat data_tp =  cv::Mat(data.cols, data.rows, CV_32F); 
cv::transpose(data, data_tp);
```

---

```
// instead, just use:
cv::Mat data_tp = data.t();
```

Comment: Does not work on a higher dimensional matrix(when `data.dims > 2`)